# Error while compiling MuPDF 1.5 using Android NDK

Tags: android, pdf, android-ndk, mupdf

I am facing a problem while compiling the new version of MuPDF 1.5 using Android NDK. 
Since there are alot of bug issues on the older version 1.4, I decided to upgrade to version 1.5 but unfortunately I've received compilation error messages as stated below:

Android NDK: WARNING:jni/Android.mk:mupdfcore: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries
[armeabi-v7a] Compile thumb  : mupdfcore <= pdf-op-run.c
jni/../../../source/pdf/pdf-op-run.c: In function 'run_xobject':
jni/../../../source/pdf/pdf-op-run.c:1732:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1.exe: some warnings being treated as errors

/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r9d/build/core/build-binary.mk:391: recipe for target 'obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdfcore/**/**/**/source/pdf/pdf-op-run.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/mupdfcore/**/**/**/source/pdf/pdf-op-run.o] Error 1

They have just released this new version 1.5 about 3 days ago. Have anyone facing the same problem? I'm using cygwin to "generate make" and compile it using ndk at platform/android. The compilation used to work for version 1.4 but not for 1.5. Hopefully someone here can help us out. Thanks.

Comment: have found any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed on the master branch of mupdf now:

http://git.ghostscript.com/?p=mupdf.git;a=blobdiff;f=source/pdf/pdf-op-run.c;h=da881b2ef56d5c1cd9ace8a3c86f5a523bc94853;hp=2bea94b791ed341063f987171b611e377cf8ffa3;hb=77315e7139a9b412ab53a7d00cd0b019bd44b497;hpb=b2f096de23e5341fbbcd7c290f3a144423741906

It's probably best to just take the latest master (as it has a number of other Android bug fixes), but this is the patch if you need it:

```
diff --git a/source/pdf/pdf-op-run.c b/source/pdf/pdf-op-run.c
index 2bea94b..da881b2 100644 (file)
--- a/source/pdf/pdf-op-run.c
+++ b/source/pdf/pdf-op-run.c
@@ -1729,7 +1729,7 @@ run_xobject(pdf_csi *csi, void *state, pdf_obj *resources, pdf_xobject *xobj, co

        /* Rethrow postponed errors */
        if (errmess[0])
-               fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, errmess);
+               fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, "%s", errmess);
 }

 static void pdf_run_BDC(pdf_csi *csi, void *state)
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind. I have solve the compiling issue. Just add %s as the argument at line 1732 to pdf-op-run.c as shown below:

fz_throw(ctx, FZ_ERROR_GENERIC, errmess, "%s");

My c code is abit rusty but hope this might help anyone who is stuck in the compiling the code.

Comment: In the MuPDF News section, the author state that "Another bug which caused a significant slowdown has also been fixed.". I'm not sure what is the slowdown is he referring to but the page rendering is somehow similar as version 1.4 which to my opinion doesn't make any difference.